# Why does White trade off into an endgame in the main line of the Hungarian Defense?

Tags: opening, italian-game, trading

I'm having trouble understanding the point of White's play in this variation (specifically `5.dxe5`):

```
[FEN ""]
1. e4 e5 2. Nf3 Nc6 3. Bc4 Be7 4. d4 d6 5. dxe5!? dxe5 6. Qxd8+ Bxd8
```

Why does White want to trade queens early, instead of keeping the tension with a move like `5.h3`? Also, why does this position have a comparatively high winrate for White (48% / 43% / 9% wins / draws / losses) according to the Lichess Masters db?

Comment: "Endgame"? With 28 men on the board?

Answer (score 2):

White has a development advantage with an extra piece in the field and therefore should be able to capture some type of initiative despite the symmetrical pawn structure.

I suggest playing through some top games in the line to see how things play out.

Answer (score 1):

White's position looks pretty active. It's basically a zero-risk opening that offers many chances to play for a win. For example, White can continue with a quick Nc3 (speculating with Nd5 ideas that will give the d8 bishop a hard time to join the game again), Be3 and 0-0-0